# Use variables from different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a ROR project. I have a navigation bar on the website which rendered from a few of controllers. I realized that it is not safe to use a `@my_name` from one of the controllers. Because this variable only appears in that controller instead of all.

Is there a way to get the same information without calling that variable directly?

```
Foo class
  def name_params
    params.require(:id)
  end

  @my_name = name_params
end
```

In the view:

```
 @my_name.eql?(@user_name) # the @user_name is a global variable
```

Comment: global methods can be defined in `ApplicationController` as helper methods, that's going to make them available in every request. But I don't know what you're retying to do here, it looks like you're making different calls/request to different controllers ?. I think you need to look for a decent ROR tutorial where you can see the lifecycle of a request, what it involves, what it has, etc.

Comment: thank you! I got it fixed. I am sorry I didn't describe the question really clear. My brain just got stuck and the way I solve it, is, check if the variable existed or not. That's why I say it is not safe to use there. I don't want to put it into ApplicationController as helper because it doesn't always exist. The value would be nil at the very beginning. I just begin learning ROR, will follow a tutorial online to ramp up.